# Given $\int_0^1 xf(x)\mathrm{d}x=0$, prove $\int_0^1 f^2(x)\mathrm{d}x\ge 4{\left(\int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)}^2$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

**Problem**: Given $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\int_0^1 xf(x)\mathrm{d}x=0$, prove that
$$
\int_0^1 f^2(x)\mathrm{d}x\ge 4{\left(\int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}x\right)}^2
$$
**Methods I've tried**:

1.
$$
\int_0^1 f^2(x)\mathrm{d}x\cdot \int_0^1 x^3\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1 f^2(x)\mathrm{d}x\cdot\frac{1}{4}\ge{\left(\int_0^1 f(x)x^{3/2}\mathrm{d}x\right)}^2
$$
Then I don't know how to deal with ${\left(\int_0^1 f(x)x^{3/2}\mathrm{d}x\right)}^2$.

2. Let $g(x)=\int_0^x f^2(t)\mathrm{d}t-4{\left(\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t\right)}^2$. Obviously $g(0)=0$. It'll suffice to prove $g'(x)\le 0\ (x\in[0,1])$.
   $$
   g'(x)=f^2(x)-8f(x)\int_0^x f(t)\mathrm{d}t
   $$
   But I don't know how to proceed further.
3. 

$$
\int_0^1 xf(x)\mathrm{d}x=0 \implies \int_0^1 f(x)\mathrm{d}{\frac{x^2}{2}}=0\implies\\ \left.f(x)\frac{x^2}{2}\right|^1_0 - \int_0^1\frac{x^2}{2}f'(x)\mathrm{d}x
$$
Then I got stuck.

The core problem here seems to be how to apply the condition $\int_0^1 xf(x)\mathrm{d}x=0$ properly. Is there an elegant way to apply this condition?

Comment: See the duplicate post [Solution prove an integral-inequality with certain initial condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172303/solution-prove-an-integral-inequality-with-certain-initial-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Find a suitable linear factor with which you can use a C-S. In other words, if you do:
$$\left(\int_0^1(ax+b)f(x)dx\right)^2\leq\int_0^1(ax+b)^2dx \int_0^1f^2(x)dx.$$

But $$\int_0^1(ax+b)f(x)dx = b\int_0^1f(x)dx,$$
so now you just need to optimize over $a,b.$ As a result, you would either get a  tighter bound or the same bound if your problem is true.

Answer (score 2):

Your first method is the most interesting because you notices that you could use Cauchy-Schwarz. If you thnik with this point of view, write $\left<f,g\right>$ for the intergal of $fg$ and $\|f\|$ for $\sqrt{\left<f,f\right>}$.

You know that $f$ is orthogonal to $\mathrm{id} : x \rightarrow x$ i.e. $\left<f,\mathrm{id}\right> = 0$ and you want to bound $\left<f,1\right>$ by $\frac{1}{2}\|f\|$. Using $\left<f,\mathrm{id}\right> = 0$, you have for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\left<f,1\right> = \left<f,1 + a\mathrm{id}\right> \leqslant \|f\|\|1 + a\mathbb{id}\|.
$$
Now, try to find the value of $a$ that makes $\|1 + a\mathrm{id}\|$ the smallest possible, you should find $\|1 + a\mathrm{id}\| = 1/2$.

This can be generalized to any Hilbert space. $|\left<f,g\right>| = \min_{h \in f^\bot}\|g + h\|$. Here, you don't know the whole $f^\bot$ but you know at least that $\mathrm{id} \in f^\bot$ so you can find sharper bounds for $\left<f,1\right>$ than when you simply use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using the [Projection Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem) for the Hilbert space $H := L^2([0,1])$ or $C([0,1])$ with the inner product $\newcommand{\bp}[1]{{\left({#1}\right)}}\newcommand{\ba}[1]{{\left\langle{#1}\right\rangle}} \ba{f,g} := \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx$ and norm $\|f\| = \ba{f,f}^{\frac12}$.

Dividing by $\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx$ we can assume without loss of generality that $\int_0^1 f(x)\, dx = 1$. Therefore the problem is to prove that if $\ba{f,x} = 0$ and $\ba{f,1} = 1$ then $\ba{f,f} \geq 4$, i.e., $\|f\| \geq 2$.

Let $A := \{f \in H : \ba{f,x} = 0, \ba{f, 1} = 1\}$, and $g(x) := -6x + 4$. We can easily verify that $g \in A$. If $f \in A$, clearly $\ba{f-g,x} = \ba{f-g,1} = 0$, so $f-g \in S := \{f \in H : \ba{f,x} = \ba{f,1} = 0\}$, a closed subspace. Conversely, if $f-g\in S$ then $f \in A$. Hence $A = S + f$. Therefore we want to prove that if $f \in S$ then $\|g-f\| \geq 2$.

Now, $$\|g\| = \bp{\int_0^1 g(x)^2\,dx}^{\frac12} = \bp{\int_0^1 (-6x+4)^2\,dx}^{\frac12} = 2$$ as we can easily verify. So what we want to prove is that $f = 0$ minimizes $\|g-f\|$ among $f \in S$. According to the Projection Theorem, this holds if and only if $g$ is orthogonal to $S$.

So we have to verify that if $f \in S$ then $\ba{g,f} = 0$. In other words, that if $\ba{f,x} = \ba{f,1} = 0$ then $\ba{g,f} = \ba{-6x+4,f} = 0$. This is clearly true, so we are done.

**A direct solution.** The above suggests the following. By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$\int_0^1 f(x)(-6x + 4) \, dx \leq \bp{\int_0^1 f(x)^2\,dx}^{\frac12} \bp{\int_0^1 (-6x + 4)^2\,dx}^{\frac12}.$$
Expanding we get $2\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx \leq \bp{\int_0^1 f(x)^2\,dx}^{\frac12}$. Changing $f(x)$ by $-f(x)$ if necessary (without loss of generality) the LHS is nonnegative, so we can square both sides and we get the desired inequality.